# TypeScript function parameter destructuring with default values

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am destructuring function parameters in TypeScript, and I have an interface that declares the basic type structure for most function parameter objects. However, there are some cases where I want to assign a default value to one of these arguments. TypeScript is not inferring the type of the assigned argument, and is instead using the type of the parameter as it is declared in the interface. How can I get TypeScript to infer the type of the default parameter?

```js
interface Args {
  foo: {};
}

function test({ foo = { bar: 1 } }: Args) {
  // typeof foo is {}, not {bar: number}
}
```

Comment: Why would it infer `{bar: number}` when `foo` is not necessarily going to be present?  You can call `test({foo: {}})` and then the default isn't used, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WGdq0w). I'm confused about why you want something different from TS. Could you make sure you're showing a [mre]?  Or [edit] to clarify the difference between expected behavior and actual behavior in light of this?

Answer (score 0):

You are explicitly telling TypeScript that your param is of type `Args`, which has a `foo` property of type `{}`. This overrides your default value's type, because you are giving it an explicit type declaration that, while wrong, doesn't create a compilation error. So TS will not be able to find the `bar` property, because it believes `foo` to be `{}`

You should fix your type declarations to reflect that `bar` is optional

Example:

```
interface Args {
  foo: {
    bar?: number
  };
}

function test({ foo = { bar: 1 } }: Args) {

}
```

Or if you cannot change `Args`:

```
interface Args {
  foo: {};
}

interface MyArgs extends Args {
  foo: Args['foo'] & {
    bar: number // Add back the "?" if bar is actually optional
  }
}

function test({ foo = { bar: 1 } }: MyArgs) {

}
```